# Android store image path to sqlite from res folder

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to store the image path from resource folder (drawable) to sqlite and then retrieve that. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE:**
After retrieving the images, I have a button here to reorder/sort the listview. That's why I need to store the image path to sqlite.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    static final int[] imgs = {
        R.drawable.dinaretreat, // 0
        R.drawable.cobterrace, // 1
        R.drawable.ventassostreet, // 2
        R.drawable.summerhillblvddrouin, // 3
        R.drawable.todmanstreetdrouin, // 4
        R.drawable.aqueductroad, // 5
        R.drawable.northroad, // 6
        R.drawable.pottsroad, // 7
        R.drawable.onemcclenaghanplace, // 8
        R.drawable.twomcclenaghanplace, // 9
        R.drawable.threemcclenaghanplace, // 10
        R.drawable.fourmcclenaghanplace, // 11
        R.drawable.fivemcclenaghanplace, // 12
        R.drawable.sevenmcclenaghanplace, // 13
        R.drawable.elevenplacemcclenaghanplace, // 14
        R.drawable.twelvemcclenaghanplace, // 15
        R.drawable.fivethreetwosummerhillblvddrouin, // 16
        R.drawable.seventeenajaxstreetdrouin, // 17
        R.drawable.onethirtythreemountainviewblvd, // 18
        R.drawable.fivethreeonesummerhillblvddrouin // 19
};


    String[] text, price;
ArrayList<String> priceList;

private DBHelper dbHelper;
Cursor cursor;

MyCustomAdapter adapter;

Button back, filter;
TextView highest, lowest, location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewhouseandland);

    initControls();

    displayRecords();
}

// TODO displayRecords
private void displayRecords() {

    checkDatabaseConnection();

    text = dbHelper.getAll();
    price = dbHelper.getAllPrices();

    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(imgs, text, price);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void initControls() {

    // TextViews
    highest = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvHighest);
    lowest = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvLowest);
    location = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvLocation);

    // Buttons
    filter = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btFilter);
    back = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btBack);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    filter.setOnClickListener(this);

    // ListView
    lv = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.lv);
    lv.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
    String strHouseName = "house_name";
    String strHousePrice = "house_price";

    textview1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        textview2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2);

        String strName = textview1.getText().toString().trim();
        String strPrice = textview2.getText().toString().trim();

    Intent i;

    i = new Intent(this, ViewHouse.class);
    i.putExtra(strHouseName, strName);
    i.putExtra(strHousePrice, strPrice);
    startActivity(i);


}

@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
private void displayDialog() {
    // TODO displayDialog
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sortBy);

    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

    promptsView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    final Spinner mSpinner= (Spinner) promptsView
            .findViewById(R.id.spDialog);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Sort By...");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.launcher);

    mSpinner.setAdapter(adp);
    mSpinner.setSelection(0);
    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int pos, long id) {
        strSpinner = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(strSpinner.equals("Highest Price")){
            highest.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            lowest.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            location.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            price = dbHelper.sortHighestPrice();

            adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(imgs, text, price);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        } else if (strSpinner.equals("Lowest Price")){
            highest.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            lowest.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            location.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT); 
            price = dbHelper.sortLowestPrice();

            adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(imgs, text, price);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else if (strSpinner.equals("Location")) {
            highest.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            lowest.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            location.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        } else {
            Log.d("Default", "Default");
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Okay",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setView(promptsView);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();


} 

    class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    String[] data_text1;
    String[] data_text2;
    int[] data_image;

MyCustomAdapter() {
    data_text1 = null;
    data_text2 = null;
    data_image = null;
}

MyCustomAdapter(int[] image, String[] house, String[] price) {
    data_text1 = house;
    data_text2 = price;
    data_image = image;
}

public int getCount() {
    return data_text1.length;
}

public String getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row;

    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);

    textview1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    textview2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);

    imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    textview1.setText(data_text1[position]);
    String strPrice = "$" + (new DecimalFormat("#,###.00")).format(Integer.parseInt(data_text2[position])) ;
    textview2.setText(strPrice);
    imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

    return (row);

    }
}
```

In here I have declared those drawables. How can I save their path to sqlite and then display them on my custom listview? Any ideas? Help is pretty much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since resources in `res` are constants, there is no need to store them in a database! Instead, just load the drawables from a resource array:

Define an array in a file such as `res/values/images.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="list_images">
        <item>@drawable/dinaretreat</item>
        <item>@drawable/cobterrace</item>
        <item>@drawable/ventassostreet</item>
        <item>@drawable/summerhillblvddrouin</item>
        <item>@drawable/todmanstreetdrouin</item>
        <item>@drawable/aqueductroad</item>
        <item>@drawable/northroad</item>
        <item>@drawable/pottsroad</item>
        <item>@drawable/onemcclenaghanplace</item>
        <item>@drawable/twomcclenaghanplace</item>
        <item>@drawable/threemcclenaghanplace</item>
        <item>@drawable/fourmcclenaghanplace</item>
        <item>@drawable/fivemcclenaghanplace</item>
        <item>@drawable/sevenmcclenaghanplace</item>
        <item>@drawable/elevenplacemcclenaghanplace</item>
        <item>@drawable/twelvemcclenaghanplace</item>
        <item>@drawable/fivethreetwosummerhillblvddrouin</item>
        <item>@drawable/seventeenajaxstreetdrouin</item>
        <item>@drawable/onethirtythreemountainviewblvd</item>
        <item>@drawable/fivethreeonesummerhillblvddrouin</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

In your `Adapter`, get the resource array, and index into it:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);

    textview1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    textview1.setText(data_text1[position]);

    textview2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text2);
    String strPrice = "$" + (new DecimalFormat("#,###.00")).format(Integer.parseInt(data_text2[position])) ;
    textview2.setText(strPrice);

    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageview.setImageResource((context.getResources().getIntArray())[position]);

    return (row);
}
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking of that, but when I am about to sort my listview, it's not changing its position.

Comment: Oh, so you are going to reorder the data in the list view? Could you please update your question with information on how you would like your code to work, or what you are trying to accomplish, and include details that you believe support needing a database?

Comment: I have to run. If you are in fact needing to store this list, I recommend NOT using a SQLite DB. That is overkill. Instead, store the list in a `JSONArray`, and read/write to `SharedPreferences`. You don't have to write a whole bunch of DB code, and SharedPreferences are way more efficient to read and write.

Comment: Can you provide for me a sample implementation of that? Thanks.

Comment: Just read up on [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html), and [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)